# Heroku doesn't recognize the Python version (which is the required one, in this case, 3.6.4)

Tags: python, git, heroku

I was deploying my code to Heroku with `git push heroku master`, but the build failed. Here is the output:

```
Counting objects: 316, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (305/305), done.
Writing objects: 100% (316/316), 12.71 MiB | 915.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 316 (delta 83), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.4 (you are using Python 3.6.4, which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.4).
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing Python 3.6.4
remote:  !     Requested runtime (Python 3.6.4) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to greensun.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/greensun.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/greensun.git'
```

As you may see, it says:

> remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.4 (you are using Python 3.6.4, which is unsupported).

How do I make Heroku recognize Python 3.6.4? (it's already installed on this Laptop with Ubuntu and the app has `runtime.txt` with content: `python-3.6.4`).

Comment: Does `runtime.txt` contain anything else? Any whitespace?

Comment: No it doesn't. However, I configured the app as python in heroku's dashboard and the error stopped appearing. I'll pass this info as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out this error stops appearing as I configured the app as Python in heroku's dashboard in buildpacks section.